# Does a quantum measurement change the state in the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurements, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse

Consider the following very basic quantum mechanics experiment.
At time $t_0$, a system $S$ is in superposition of two orthogonal states $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$, which we could describe by $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |A\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |B\rangle$.
This remains so until a later time $t_1$.
At this time, an observer $O$ observes the state of $S$. Let's say that it collapses to $|A\rangle$.

Now, what has happened to the state at $t_0$? I can think of two possible answers:

1. The state at $t_0$ was $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |A\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |B\rangle$.
2. The state at $t_0$ has now been 'updated' to $|A\rangle$.

Answer 1 seems to be logical because then the past doesn’t change.

Answer 2 corresponds more to my (classical) intuition: I have discovered that it is state A, so of course it has always been this way.

Please let me know which of these two is the correct answer, from the perspective of mainstream quantum mechanics.

Comment: Nothing "happened to" the state at $t_0$. The state at $t_0$ has already been posited to be $|\psi_0\rangle \propto |A\rangle+|B\rangle$, you can't change what you already told us about that state. The state propagates from time $t_0$ to $t_1$ to become $e^{-i\hat H (t_1-t_0)}|\psi_0\rangle$. The measurement was made at $t_1$ and you already told us the result is the eigenvalue of $|A\rangle$ so at $t_1$ the state collapses to $|A\rangle$. The probability to have measured $|A\rangle$ at $t_1$ is $|\langle A|e^{-i\hat H t}|\psi_0\rangle|^2$. You can't retroactively change $|\psi_0\rangle$.

Comment: I have edited my question, it is now only about mainstream physics.

Comment: Please let me know why this question is not about mainstream physics. If a question is closed, shouldn't this be explained in a comment?

Comment: Is there something that is not explained here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539

Comment: Yes, this says that non-mainstream physics is not allowed but my question is about a very simple and basic concept in quantum mechanics which is a mainstream theory

Comment: Could you clarify here in one sentence what is the "very simple and basic concept in quantum mechanics" that you are asking about?

Comment: That concept would be ‘the wavefunction of an object, at different moments in time’

Comment: Questions about that concept seem to have already been answered. The wavefunction evolve in time two ways: 1) smoothly, according to the unitary operator $\hat U = e^{-i\hat H t}$, $\psi \to \hat U \psi$; 2) abruptly, due to measurement $\psi \to \phi$, where $\phi$ is the eigenstate corresponding to the eigenvalue of the observable that was measured.

Comment: Instead of trying to salvage this question, I think it would be easier for you to carefully rethink your question and then create a new, clear, and well-defined question post.

Comment: In your new question, you should keep in mind that *causality* is an important concept of accepted mainstream physics.

Comment: I think your current answer clearly answers my question, but I do not know how to rethink my question

Answer (score 2):

> Does a quantum measurement change the state in the past?

No.

Or, at least, it is completely inconsistent with mainstream theory (and well-known results like the Born rule) to say that a measurement in the present would change the already-posited past state vector.

> Consider the following experiment.
> At time $t_0$, a system $S$ is in superposition of two orthogonal states $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$, which we could describe by $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |A\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2 |B\rangle$.
> This remains so until a later time $t_1$.
> At this time, an observer $O$ observes the state of $S$. Let's say that it collapses to $|A\rangle$.

> Now, what has happened to the state at $t_0$?

Nothing "happened to" the state at $t_0$.

The state at $t_0$ has already been posited (by you) to be
$$|\psi_0\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|A\rangle+|B\rangle\right)\;,
$$ and you can't retroactively change what you already told us about that state. This state just describes our knowledge of the system, and it is based on what you already told us in your own thought experiment. This state doesn't tell us anything about what the "actual" value of some measurement is or will be, other than via probabilities predicted by the Born rule.

The state $|\psi_0\rangle$ propagates from time $t_0$ to $t_1$ to become $e^{-i\hat H (t_1-t_0)}|\psi_0\rangle$. This unitary evolution of the state in time is a basic postulate of quantum mechanics.

As part of your assertions about this thought experiment, you asserted that a measurement was made at $t_1$ and you already told us the result is the eigenvalue of $|A\rangle$, call it $A$.

Thus, at $t_1$ the state collapses to $|A\rangle$. Please remember that "collapse" is not a physical collapse like an implosion, it just describes how our knowledge of the system, as encoded in the wavefunction, has to be updated based on the facts of the world (i.e., that we measured the value $A$.)

The probability to have measured $|A\rangle$ at $t_1$ is calculated via the usual Born rule: $|\langle A|e^{-i\hat H (t_1 - t_0)}|\psi_0\rangle|^2$.

You can't retroactively change $|\psi_0\rangle$ without changing the predicted probabilty, which is already given correctly by the Born rule (per mainstream quantum mechanics).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is ‘mainstream quantum mechanics’ here the same as the Kopenhagen Interpretation?

Comment: I don't know. I just mean "mainstream quantum mechanic" to mean quantum mechanics as it has been taught in textbooks for almost 100 years now. Like Dirac's book in the 1930s, Messiah's book in the 1960s, Sakurai's books in the 1990s, etc.

Comment: At this link they equate ‘Copenhagen’ with ‘textbook’: https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=11202#:~:text=The%20traditional%20“Copenhagen”%20or%20“,do%20a%20measurement%20or%20observation.

Comment: Yes, they do that there.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not have any consequence that can be measured by experiment, so doesn't need to be answered by Physics.

In the non-relativistic theory, two intertial frames are related by a Galiliean transformation, so they have the same absolute time-coordinate, with possible shift.  If the measurement is done by time $t_1$ for frame A, and time $t_1^\prime$ for frame B, both see any event prior to the measurement as occuring in their past, so there is no measurable consequence to hypothesizing what the state might have been in a time that is in the past of a measurement.

In the relativistic theory, two inertial frames are related by a time-like proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation (with possible shift of the coordinates).  Such a transformation has the property that it maps future-pointing time-like or light-like vectors to future-pointing time-like or light-like vectors.  This means, that if a measurement was done in time $t_1$ for frame A and time $t_1^\prime$ for frame B, both frames see the same past time-cone of the measurement, so any event that happened in the past for frame A, is also in the past for frame B.  So again, there is no measurable consequence to speculating about revising the state of the system after a measurement.  What's in the past is left in the past.

On the other hand, if you had a reference frame travelling faster than light, then you get a space-like transformation between the reference frames, and a space-like transformation can reverse the order of past and future.  So were it possible to travel faster than light, this question would have to be answered since the answer could be tested by experiment.

Comment: Welcome @ChadK! You make a very interesting point here: it can not be verified by experiment if the past has ‘changed’. I think this is exactly what happens with the various interpretations of QM: they can not be tested by experiments either.